# What's the difference between typedef const struct *CGPath and typedef struct *CGPath?

Tags: iphone, c

I've found this in the CGPath.h header file. I'm curious what this const thing does?

```
typedef struct CGPath *CGMutablePathRef;
typedef const struct CGPath *CGPathRef;
```

My guess: If I typedef something as const, it's constant so immutable and can't be changed in any way. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the `const` means you cannot change the path externally.

---

For CoreFoundation-based libraries though, the `const` is more a hack to allow mutable objects to use immutable methods without casting, and *not* vice-versa. That means

```
CGMutablePathRef mpath;
...
CGPathContainsPoint(mpath, ...);
```

compiles fine because a `Foo*` can be implicitly converted to a `const Foo*`, but

```
CGPathRef path;
...
CGPathAddRect(path, ...);
```

will throw an error because a `const Foo*` cannot be safely converted to a `Foo*`.

Answer (score 2):

`const T*` means that the type is a pointer and that the pointee cannot be changed via that pointer. (That doesn't necessarily mean that the pointee can never change; it might be modified by a different, non-`const` reference to it, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

"In any way" might be an overstatement, but you're correct. You'll notice that one is called CGPathRef and the other is CG**Mutable**PathRef.

Answer (score 1):

const is from standard C. It means that the dereferenced pointer cannot be assigned to. So I cannot do:

```
GCPathRef p = &my_path;
*p = new_path;  // generates compiler error
```

But note that p itself *can* be changed:

```
p = &another_path; // this is OK.
```

It is not a hack at all as another poster has suggested. It has been part of C for generations.